# Spring AOP not executing @Around

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I have a method definition like :

```
public String testing (String requestPayload, String certificatePath, String certPassword, String urlToHit, String method, String soapAction, int timeOut) throws KeyStoreException, FileNotFoundException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException
```

I am trying to create @Around advice for this method like:

```
@Around("execution(* com.sams.pharmacy.connector.webservice.RxService.testing(..) throws java.security.KeyStoreException, java.io.FileNotFoundException, java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException, java.security.cert.CertificateException,  java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException, java.security.KeyManagementException)")
public void around(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {}
```

I have tried giving "**" instead of all Exception names, tried giving public void instead of "*" , but nothing seems to work.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you annotated your class with `@Aspect`?

Comment: Yes, I have already done that.